# AsyncTask executes twice when it should do it once

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

I hope someone can help me. I have an AsyncTask to create an interface to be processed later by the server. It sends JSON to a php page with a HTTP call. This AsyncTask is executed when the user clicks a button. This is not a very common issue, it happens maybe three or four time a day. But sometimes it happens that the AsynTask creates two interfaces (it is executed twice) with just one click.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import com.picking.adapters.JSONParser;
import com.picking.utils.Config;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class CreateInterface extends AsyncTask<String, String, HashMap<String, String>> {
    //Progress Dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    //Variables
    JSONObject interfaceJSON;
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;
    private Context context;
    private HashMap<String, String> messageHashMap;


    //Constructor
    public CreateInterface(Context context, JSONObject interfaceJSON, OnTaskCompleted listener) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.interfaceJSON = interfaceJSON;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.creating_interface));
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequestJSON(Config.url_create_interface, "POST", interfaceJSON, context);
        } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        messageHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            if (json != null) {
                int success = json.getInt(Config.TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    messageHashMap.put(Config.TAG_RESULT, Config.TAG_OK);
                    messageHashMap.put(Config.TAG_MESSAGE, json.getString(Config.TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return messageHashMap;
                } else {
                    messageHashMap.put(Config.TAG_RESULT, Config.TAG_ERROR);
                    messageHashMap.put(Config.TAG_MESSAGE, json.getString(Config.TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return messageHashMap;
                }
            } else {
                messageHashMap.put(Config.TAG_RESULT, Config.TAG_ERROR);
                messageHashMap.put(Config.TAG_MESSAGE, "Error en la respuesta del servidor. Probablemente no se haya creado la interfaz");
                return messageHashMap;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, String> messageHashMap) {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onTaskComplete(messageHashMap);
        }
    }
}
```

It is posible that the AsyncTask executes twice by itself? Is there any way to avoid that?
Thanks in advance.

The AsyncTask is called from a ListActivity buy click on the bttFile. Then a DialogFragment pops up with the Accept and Cancel buttons. When the user clicks on Accept the method which creates the json is executed and at the end the AsyncTask is called
The code is this

```
// import...

public class PickingActivity extends ListActivity implements EditDialogFragment.EditDialogListener, CustomDialogListener, InterfazDialogListener {

 //......................
    private Button bttFile;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   ///     ...................
        bttFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttFile);
        bttFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //if (!isFinishedPedido || (isCamara4 && !isFinishedCamara4)) {
                if (!isFinishedPedido) {
                    AlertDialogFragment alertDialogFragmentPedidoNoFinalizado = new AlertDialogFragment().newInstance(getResources().getString(R.string.pedido_NO_finalizado));
                    alertDialogFragmentPedidoNoFinalizado.show(getFragmentManager(), "alertDialog3");
                } else {
                    if (!isCamara4) {
                        ((PickingLineasListaHolderAdapter) getListView().getAdapter()).getFilter().filter("2");
                        customDialogFragment = new CustomDialogFragment().newInstance(getResources().getString(R.string.crear_interfaz_texto_dialogo));
                        customDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "customDialog");
                    } else {
                        dismissDialog();
                        Intent i = new Intent(PickingActivity.this, GetNoteActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onCustomDialogPositiveClick() {
        ArrayList<PickingLineas> pickingLineasArrayListOrdered = getPickingLineasArrayList();
        Collections.sort(pickingLineasArrayListOrdered, new Comparator<PickingLineas>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(PickingLineas pl1, PickingLineas pl2) {
                if (pl1 == null) {
                    if (pl2 == null) {
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        return 1; 
                    }
                } else if (pl2 == null) {
                    return -1;
                }
                Integer n1 = pl1.numLineaSAP;
                Integer n2 = pl2.numLineaSAP;
                if (n1 == null) {
                    if (n2 == null) {
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        return 1; // this will put null names after non null names
                    }
                } else if (n2 == null) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (0 == n1) {
                    if (0 == n2) {
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (0 == n2) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
                return Integer.compare(n1, n2);
            }
        });
        exportarArchivo(pickingLineasArrayListOrdered);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCustomDialogNegativeClick() {
        customDialogFragment.dismiss();
    }


    private void exportarArchivo(ArrayList<PickingLineas> plarrayList) {

      //.... we create the JSON....
        try {
            jsonObject.put("interfaz", "0");
            jsonObject.put("note", note);
            jsonObject.put("contador", contador);
            jsonObject.put("cabecera", cabecera);
            jsonObject.put("lineas", jsonArrayLineas);
            jsonObject.put("detalle", jsonArrayDetalle);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Comprobamos WIFI STATUS
        if (getWifiStatus().get(Config.TAG_WIFI_STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            new CreateInterface(PickingActivity.this, jsonObject, new CreateInterfaceTaskCompleteListener()).execute();
        } else {
            NetworkUtil.showWifiMessage(PickingActivity.this, "No se puede enviar pedido a facturación");
        }
    }


    private class CreateInterfaceTaskCompleteListener implements OnTaskCompleted<HashMap<String, String>> {
        @Override
        public void onTaskComplete(HashMap<String, String> messageHashMap) {
            if (messageHashMap != null) {
                String resultMessage = "";
                String resultState = "";
                resultMessage = messageHashMap.get(Config.TAG_MESSAGE);
                resultState = messageHashMap.get(Config.TAG_RESULT);
                Log.e("pickingresult", resultState + "-" + resultMessage);
                setResultState(resultState);
                if (messageHashMap.get(Config.TAG_RESULT).equalsIgnoreCase(Config.TAG_OK)) {
                    InterfazDialogFragment interfazDialogFragment = new InterfazDialogFragment().newInstance(resultMessage);
                    interfazDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "interfazDialogFragment");
                } else {
                    CustomToast customToast = new CustomToast(PickingActivity.this,
                            resultMessage,
                            Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    customToast.show();
                }
            } else {
                CustomToast customToast = new CustomToast(PickingActivity.this,
                        "Problemas en la creación de la interfaz",
                        Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                customToast.show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: where you are calling AsyncTask ? can you add that code file.

Comment: Are you sure its actually THE `AsyncTask` that executes twice and not your code inside the `AsycTask?` And how do you initialize the inner AsyncTask class? Try also to put some `Log.d();` in your AsyncTask override method and see if they are called twice

Comment: it's probably where you called the `AsyncTask.execute()` ... are you calling from a fragment or an activity that is getting created more than once !?

Comment: I've edited my question with the rest of the code